# Disabling and enabling content using Customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a form at the bottom of my WordPress theme that I want to give the user the ability to disable. I'm not sure if I should install it as a custom plugin or create a section within the WordPress Customizer that can disable the form. Which is the easier option?

This is the code I used to create a section within my Customizer. I didn't understand how to use the `body_class` filter to create a class.

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 
    'RSVP', 
    array( // adding section called "RSVP"
        'title'       => 'RSVP',
        'priority'    => 800,
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
        'description' => 'Disable the RSVP form at the footer.'
    ) 
);   
$wp_customize->add_setting( // adding setting
    'rsvp-on[rsvp_setting]', 
    array(
        'default'    => '1', // think this means it's checked.
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options'
        //'sanitize_callback' => ''    
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control( // adding control
    'rsvp-on', 
    array(
        'label'    => 'RSVP form enabled', 
        'section'  => 'RSVP',
        'settings' => 'rsvp-on[rsvp_setting]', // rsvp-on is the slug
        'type'     => 'checkbox' 
    )
);    
add_filter( 'body_class', 'woodsy_body_classes' );
function woodsy_rsvp_class( $classes ) {  
    $my_theme_settings = get_option( 'rsvp-on' );
    $classes[] = $rsvp-on['rsvp_setting'];   
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: I have the opinion that, in general, forms are plugin territory. But hide/show a theme section is theme territory. So, you could have a plugin that handle the form, so you can reuse it across themes, and you could have a option in the theme to hide/show some part of the layout, with or without the form.

Comment: mirae2000 Few notes: when you say "I want to give the **user** the ability ... " do we presume you intended the wp-admin user, and not the final user who looks at a website?  Dunno about you, but less is more.. keep it simple, really simple.  Add a `Display form at bottom of page: [ ]` element in the native left margin Appearance --> Customize location via wp_customize.  Does the current theme show other custom choices to the wp-admin user within the Appearance box? That could complicate things. Now the wp-admin user has to figure at what is where, ugh.  Did I mention to keep it simple?

Comment: zipzit: Definitely the admin user, not any website user. I agree in keeping things as simple as possible. I already modified the current customizer panel quite a bit. I am able to figure out drop-down menus for font selection and color customization, etc., but am struggling with adding and deleting actual content within the site. That is what my question is trying to address.

Comment: To put it simply, I am trying to allow the admin the ability to turn this line of code on and off within my footer.php file: <?php get_template_part( 'rsvp' ); ?>

Comment: Ok, figured it out using a conditional statement in my footer.php!    <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'hide_rsvp' ) == '') { ?>
         <?php get_template_part( 'rsvp' ); ?>
         <?php } // end if ?>